# Yammer OpenGraph commenting widget loading all feed, but not specific page messages

Tags: widget, facebook-opengraph, yammer, comments

On our site we integrated OpenGraph commenting widget https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/commenting

And it worked fine. But recently (maybe several days ago) it stop working like it was. And loading messages not only for current page, but all messages which user have in his Yammer feed.

Is there some changes in API?